# Why isn't this rails gem being loaded in production on unicorn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, require, unicorn

I'm using the [humanize_boolean](https://github.com/parabuzzle/humanize_boolean) gem in a Ruby on Rails application.

The gem works great for me, except one important place and that's my production webserver. I don't blame this gem for my problem, but I'd love any help someone else's eyeballs can provide here.

In a view template, I use humanize. But I get

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `humanize' for true:TrueClass):
```

And indeed, the humanize_boolean gem hasn't been included. I can tell when I use `$LOADED_FEATURES`, `humanize_boolean.rb` is not in the list, though it is in development.

The following convince me that it should be working:

- When I use the production console like `RAILS_ENV=production rails c`, it works. E.g. `true.humanize` prints "Yes" as expected.
- In my Gemfile, I have gem 'humanize_boolean' not in any group. Thus, it should be required in production.
- It works in an email template for an email that's sent by Sidekiq in production.

I'm using unicorn as the app server.

If I manually require the files in my controller, it works. E.g.

```
require '/home/ubuntu/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/humanize_boolean-0.0.1/lib/humanize_boolean/version.rb'
require '/home/ubuntu/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/humanize_boolean-0.0.1/lib/humanize_boolean.rb'

class ClientsController < ApplicationController
...
```

Also, it works if I use webrick in production, e.g.

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rails s
```

So somehow this is a problem with unicorn, but I have no other such problems. Bizarre.

Comment: there are no good reasons for this. especially when it works in Sidekick. did you try turning it off and on again?

Comment: Eventually it worked. I have no idea what I did. I swear I had restarted unicorn multiple times, including at least one full deployment from capistrano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your unicorn.rb file:

```
before_exec do |server| 
  ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] = "/path/to/app/current/Gemfile" 
end
```

That should ensure that the gemfile is loaded before unicorn starts.

Comment: Hey Mike. I was sure it was loading my Gemfile because every other gem was loaded fine.

Comment: I just want to see if that works... I'm not able to replicate your problem on my end here. I what version of rails and unicorn are you running?

Comment: Sorry. To be clear, it's not a problem, as I updated my question. But just in case I'm using Rails 4.1.0 and Unicorn 4.6.2. Thanks for your input on this!

Comment: Thanks. I have seen where Unicorn (sometimes) has trouble loading gems in the gemfile in production. It seems to be related to env caching of some sort and restarting everything usually fixes it. If you want to prevent that from happening for sure in the future, you can add the before_exec block I posted and never worry about it again ;)

Comment: I added another gem today ([constructor](https://github.com/atomicobject/constructor)). Unicorn had the same problem, although this time it was with this new gem, not the humanize gem. So as a guess, it's got some gemfile cache. Your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't specifically answer your question, but I'd advise you skip the gem and use a helper:

```
def human_boolean(boolean)
  boolean ? "Yes" : "No"
end

human_boolean(true)
# => "Yes"

human_boolean(false)
# => "No"
```

I'm only suggesting this because a gem is overpowered for such a simple piece of code.

Comment: Any reason why it'd be considered "overpowered"? It's essentially just reading in another file and then parsing that. Even though I don't use the i18n capabilities, it seems great to use gems when possible, as someone else maintains and tests them.

Comment: @TylerCollier I'd consider it overpowered because the gem can be implemented in 3 lines. Less code, less code to maintain, less code to test, more explicit and easily accessed in your helper. It's definitely wise to leverage other people's code where possible, but not in cases where you can implement the same thing within 10 seconds.

Comment: You can even implement the i18n capabilities in a single line. It's such a simple case, that there is no reason to use a gem. It's another dependency, added startup time and memory consumption for the sake of 3 lines? The trade-off isn't worth it. If you'd use a helper (shouldn't have to require anything -- they are automatically loaded), then you wouldn't have even wasted time on this very question because it would have Just Worked.

Comment: Just going to throw this out there (I may be biased).. but, the gem supports i18n and provides humanize function directly to the TrueClass and FalseClass which means its available anywhere in the app and follows the "humanize" paradigm that active support provides for strings. If you put it in a helper it won't be available in the controller or model unless you include that helper in. Sure, there may be no reason for including it in there but, in my humble opinion, having it as a gem is the cleaner solution for including such functionality and follows the established "humanize" paradigm.

Comment: yes, you are biased ;) If it is a natural progression for the "humanize" paradigm, why not just add it to the Rails core?